# Lazy `SignalProducer` that fetches more data asynchronously when all data has been consumed

Tags: frp, reactive-cocoa-4

Let's imagine that we can fetch a fixed number of messages asynchronously (one request, containing N elements)

```
func fetchMessages(max: UInt, from: Offset) ->  SignalProducer<Message,NoError>
```

Now, I'd like to turn this into an unbounded `SignalProducer` that will lazily call `fetchMessages` when the previous stream completes.

```
func stream(from: Offset) -> SignalProducer<Message, NoError> {
    // challenge is to implement this function
}
```

An initial idea that could work, but that would still require pre-computing all the ranges would be to genericize the following code

```
func lazyFetchFrom(from: Offset) -> SignalProducer<Message,NoError> {
        return SignalProducer<Message,NoError> { (observer, disposable) in
            fetchMessages(from).start(observer)
        }
    }

    let lazyStream =
        fetchMessages(1000, from)
            .concat(lazyFetchFrom(from + 1000))
            .concat(lazyFetchFrom(from + 2000))
            .... // could probably be done generically using a flatMap
```

Now, I'd like to go one step further and evaluate the next call to lazyFetchFrom once the previous values have been consumed. Is that possible?

Thanks

PS: to be clear, my main concern is to provide some sort of backpressure so that the producer doesn't produce too quickly compared to the consumer

Edit: [here is](https://gist.github.com/samidalouche/8a317a55a888072751d95be93637bdc7) my latest attempt at implementing some backpressure. However, when we observeOn the signal, the backpressure disappears, and everything is queued in memory

Comment: I right understand what you need recursive fetch all data use pagination? If it yes, I have this solution on rac2 and I can re-write it on rac4 if need

Comment: In rac2 solution this problem used RACCommand with enable allowsConcurrentExecution and aggregate response

Comment: Yes, I need to recursively fetch all data using pagination. If I have a solution in RAC2, I can probably translate it into RAC4. 

I played a little bit with RAC on the side to understand when the producer-consumer mechanism provides built-in backpressure, and what I found is that the producer will be blocked by the consumer if I do not specify any `startOn` or `observeOn`, but things will accumulate forever if the consumer is observing on a different scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (RACSignal *)allContentFromId:(NSInteger)contentId afterDate:(NSDate *)date fetchSize:(NSInteger)fetchSize {
    RACSignal *signalNextPagination = [self nextPaginationAllContentFromId:contentId afterDate:date fetchSize:fetchSize];

    //in signalNextPagination will be send next fetch size data and send complete only after downloaded all data
    //so we used aggregate

    return [signalNextPagination aggregateWithStart:@[] reduce:^id(NSArray *before, NSArray *next) {
        return [before arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:next];
    }];
}


- (RACSignal *)nextPaginationAllContentFromId:(NSInteger)contentId afterDate:(NSDate *)date fetchSize:(NSInteger)fetchSize {

    //command will be send one fetch request
    //after recv data in command need try size fetch
    //if size eq fetch size, so need repeat command with new offset

    RACCommand *command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(NSDate *date) {
        return [self requestContentFromId:contentId afterDate:date limit:fetchSize];
    }];
    command.allowsConcurrentExecution = YES;

    RACSignal *download = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [[command.executionSignals flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
            return value;
        }] subscribeNext:^(NSArray *datas) {
            [subscriber sendNext:datas];
            if ([datas count] == fetchSize) {
                NSDate *date = [[datas firstObject] pubDate];
                [command execute:date];
            } else {
                [subscriber sendCompleted];
            }
        } error:^(NSError *error) {
            [subscriber sendError:error];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }];

        [command execute:date];
        return nil;
    }];

    return download;
}
```

Comment: You are completed?

Comment: So, here is the implementation I came up with, but that doesn't provide backpressure as soon as `observeOn` is called on the signal...

https://gist.github.com/samidalouche/8a317a55a888072751d95be93637bdc7

If anyone has an idea of how to improve the implementation so that the next batch is fetched only when the observer actually reaches the end of the stream (rather than some magic proxy that RAC seems to be using), it would be great